# JSP JSR45 debug: Smart Step Into does not work

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

"Smart Step Into" option in JSP file not working with JSR45 debug, but it is working fine with normal Java code debug. When I click Ctl+F7 it straight goes into the first method instead of giving popup.

Also, with JSR45 plugin, debug point never stop inside an anonymous class.

I am using IntellijIdea Ultimate 2016.3.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an open bug (and you are aware of that since you have commented it):

- [IDEA-166359](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-166359) JSP JSR45 debug: Smart Step Into does not work

I doubt that you will get a better response here than in YouTrack from JetBrains developers.

Comment: I ask this question to find out if there is any workaround which I didn't found at YouTrack.